# How do I automatically update events in my secondary Google Calendar every time I edit my primary calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-apps-script

I have a calendar with events that all happen at the same place. Let's call it my primary calendar.

I want to create a secondary calendar and automatically fill it with events "Transport" that happen before the first and after the last primary event of that day.

Some of the primary events repeat every week or every two weeks.

How do I do it? Is it possible to do it without scripting?

Comment: Google Calendar is not quite that sophisticated.